# Nginx SSL for all subdomains

Tags: nginx

I want to access nginx subdomains on SSL also. I tried different want it didn't work. I am using let's encrypt.
SSL is working on 1.example.com but I want to access *.1.example.com on SSL.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name 1.example.de;

    # Strict Transport Security
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

I also tried

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name *.1.example.com;

    # Strict Transport Security
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

I want to access abc.1.example.com on SSL

I am getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: Please be more specific about "didn't work". what's the exact error message you encountered?

Comment: Also, your config is missing the https server section for those subdomains.

Comment: I am getting DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: How do you test? Be specific! Show us the complete command and the complete output.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mta-sts.3001.dk;
# enforce https
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

in all the configuartion files for my sites, and then

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubdomains";
```

in the server block for port 443.

Answer (score 0):

If DNS fails to look for the IP address, you may receive DNS errors like "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN". Please check your DNS record. Maybe your resolver has an wrong record cached.

Answer (score -1):

you can use https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx
auto install subdomain other domain 
with one click

Comment: Certbot isn't going to help when DNS isn't configured.

Comment: just use regular exertion * for all subdomain  and validate the sub in the  conf